Is it possible to use a run-time variable in the ref property of resources?
Is it possible to use a variable in the ref property of resources in ADO YAML other than the pre-defined variables? I'm on ADO 2022, so my version supports this feature
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: myRepo
      type: git
      name: myProject/myRepo
      ref:  ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}

I know pre-defined variables would work as shown above but I want to determine the ref based on the branch I'm building. I.e if I'm building master or the release branch, I need to use the 'master' as ref for myRepo and if I'm building develop or a feature branch, I need to use 'develop' as ref for myRepo branch
variables:
  - group: Pipelineparameters
  - group: octopus
  - name: devOpsbranchName
    ${{ if or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature/develop'),eq(variables['System.PullRequest.targetBranchName'], 'refs/heads/develop'),startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature/')) }}: 
      value: 'develop'
    ${{ else }}:
      value: 'master'
  - template: ADOYAML/Variables/build.yaml@devops      
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: devops
      name: myProject/devops
      type: git
      ref: ${{ variables['devOpsbranchName'] }}


stages:
  - stage: Prepare
    displayName: "Prepare"
    jobs:
      #set variable for environment based on branch
      - job: setvars
        displayName: "Set Pipeline variables"
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: echo ${{ variables['devOpsbranchName'] }}
          - template: ADOYAML/Build/buildENVs.yaml@devops

I tried the above code but its always getting the master branch for devops repo, no matter which branch I'm building(master the is default branch for devops repo)
When I echo the value of the variable inside the job(setvars), it prints out the correct value for the variable devOpsbranchName.
What am I missing?

Hi @user18610347, Good day. Have you got a chance to check the answers below? The current evaluation of the variable System.PullRequest.targetBranchName is not working as it is not available in template expressions. Hope your concerns in this post can be resolved. Thx.

Did you have any chance to take a look at the answers below?

Template expressions are supported for the ref property of the repository resource, but not all predefined variables can be used in templates, though.
Analysing your condition:

${{ if or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], '...'),eq(variables['System.PullRequest.targetBranchName'], '...),startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], '...')) }}:

Build.SourceBranch variable is available in templates, but System.PullRequest.targetBranchName is NOT. That's why your ${{ if... }} expression might not work as expected.
To check if a predefined variable can be used in templates, check the Available in templates? column in the predefined variables documentation:


Thank you @rui-jarimba for your response! Thanks to you I learnt something new today, about not all pre-defined variables are available in templates.
My if statement has 'or' condition, so it should have resolved to the correct value. Besides, when I echo the value of the variable inside a job, it is echo'ing the correct value.

@user18610347 double-check your condition, but as already mentioned System.PullRequest.targetBranchName is NOT available in templates. I don't believe this condition will work properly for all scenarios because eq(variables['System.PullRequest.targetBranchName'], 'refs/heads/develop') in a template expression probably always return false.

As far as I have tested, you may set ref: $(devOpsbranchName)for your repo resource to dynamically checkout the expected branches, while the pipeline is triggered by CI or manually.
variables:
  - name: devOpsbranchName
    ${{ if or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature/develop'),eq(variables['System.PullRequest.targetBranchName'], 'refs/heads/develop'),startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature/')) }}: 
      value: 'develop'
    ${{ else }}:
      value: 'master'
  - name: resources
    value: $[convertToJson(resources)]

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: devops
      name: myProject/devops
      type: git
      ref: $(devOpsbranchName)

stages:
  - stage: Prepare
    displayName: "Prepare"
    jobs:
      #set variable for environment based on branch
      - job: setvars
        displayName: "Set Pipeline variables"
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - powershell: |
              echo 'Build.SourceBranch - $(Build.SourceBranch)'
              echo 'devOpsbranchName - $(devOpsbranchName)'
              echo '$(resources)'


However, when the pipeline is triggered by a PR, the value of the variable Build.SourceBranch is refs/pull/{prId}/merge rather than any value that startsWith refs/heads/feature/. Plus, the fact that the variable System.PullRequest.targetBranchName is NOT available in template expressions at compile time as RUI mentioned, the ${{if}} conditional insertion will very much likely to be expanded as  ${{ if or(eq('refs/pull/{prId}/merge', 'refs/heads/feature/develop'),eq(NULL, 'refs/heads/develop'),startsWith('refs/pull/{prId}/merge', 'refs/heads/feature/')) }}: thus evaluated as or(false, false, false) = false.


With those being said, we are unable to set the ref property of the repo resource according to the target branch of PR as of now, while you may consider other conditions such as eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest').

No this is not possible right now1, by combining ref: $(devOpsbranchName)2 with a runtime expression for devOpsbranchName
For example we can use replace to create an inline if for runtime expressions
I changed

System.PullRequest.targetBranchName to System.PullRequest.targetBranch because only the latter has a refs/heads prefix
eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature/develop') to eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop') because refs/heads/feature/* is already part of startswith
|- is important to avoid an additional newline after the branch name

variables:
  - name: devopsBranchName
    value: |-
      $[ replace(
          replace(
            or(
              eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'),
              eq(variables['System.PullRequest.targetBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'),
              startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature/')
            ),
            True,
            'develop'
          ),
          False,
          'master'
        )
      ]
  # Only For Debugging
  - name: resources
    value: $[ convertToJson(resources) ]
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: devops
    name: myProject/devops
    type: git
    ref: $(devopsBranchName)
steps:
- bash: echo '$(resources)'
- bash: echo '$(devopsBranchName)'
- bash: echo '$(Build.Reason)'
- bash: echo '$(System.PullRequest.targetBranch)'


1 at least on Azure Devops Services at the time of this answer this is only working for checkout, failure to answer this I guess
This works for checkout: devops, but for template: file.yml@devops you get the following error /azure-pipeline.yml: Could not get the latest source version for repository Library hosted on Azure Repos using ref refs/heads/$(devopsBranchName).
2 No I didn't know this feature exist before the post of Alvin Zhao, documentation is bad at explaining expression availability per type (template ${{ ... }} vs runtime $[ ... ] vs macro $( ... ) ), after testing more this looks like a hallucination that works sometimes
